# PyCharm chaning color of warning messages

Tags: python, pycharm

Sometimes PyCharms returns warnings like:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

They are in red, just like "proper errors". This makes it  inconvenient to read the output. Is there a way to change the color of warnings to, say blue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

Settings -> Editor -> inspections

but no blue color